# Read entered value on input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment that says :
"After entering the email address in the form, the given email should be showed in this div tag `<div class="your-mail"></div>`"

The HTML looks like this :

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <main>  
            <h2>Newsletter abonnieren</h2>
            <br>
            <div>
                <a class="help" href="">Need Help?</a><br>
                <p class="explanation">...............</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <form name="subscription" action="test.html" method="post">
                <input class="email-abonieren" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre Email"><br>
                <input class="submit-button" type="button" value="Newsletter abbonieren">
            </form>
            <br>
            <div class="your-mail"></div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

This is what I have so far :

```
var emailField = document.getElementsByName("email");
var newsletter = document.querySelector('.submit-button');
newsletter.addEventListener('click', function() {});`
```

Thank you

Comment: FYI `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. You can do `document.getElementsByName("email")[0]` to get the first element in the collection.

Comment: Or just `document.querySelector('[name="email"]')`. Either way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newsletter.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".your-mail").innerText = emailField[0].value
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but Im getting this error on the console now : 
TypeError: document.selector is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: I had a little typo, I've edited my answer

Comment: Yes I just tried that too, what it does is it just gives it back on the site(browser)

Comment: EDIT: I understand now, the div is empty so thats whats happening, thanks a lot man !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onkeyup" event for this.

```
<div class="wrap">
        <main>  
            <h2>Newsletter abonnieren</h2>
            <br>
            <div>
                <a class="help" href="">Need Help?</a><br>
                <p class="explanation">...............</p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <form name="subscription" action="test.html" method="post">
                <input class="email-abonieren" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre Email" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"><br>
                <input class="submit-button" type="button" value="Newsletter abbonieren">
            </form>
            <br>
            <div class="your-mail"></div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script>
       function myFunction(value) {
          $(".your-mail").text(value);
      }
    </script>
```